# Rating Record Is Not getting save in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Controller=>>
view is sending data to SendRating and this method is responsible for storing data in database,,but data is not getting saved.
only authenticated user can rate ,but every time we faced rating failed..i can't understand what exactly the problem is.

```
public ActionResult SendRating(string r, string s, string id, string url)
        {
            try {
                var context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            string currentUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            int autoid = 0;
            Int16 thisVote = 0;
            Int16 O_ServID = 0;
            Int16.TryParse(s, out O_ServID);
            Int16.TryParse(r, out thisVote);
            int.TryParse(id, out autoid);

            if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return Json("Not authenticated!");
            }



            switch (s)
            {
                case "5":
                        //var isIt = db.VoteModel.Where(v => v.O_ServID == O_ServID && v.UserId.Equals(User.Identity.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) && v.WorkerID == autoid).FirstOrDefault();


                        var service = context.OrderServices.Where(o => o.O_ServID == O_ServID).Single();
                        var worker = context.Workers.Where(w => w.WorkerID == autoid).Single();
                        var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
                        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
                        var user = userManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
                        VoteModel vm = new VoteModel()
                    {
                        Active = true,
                        //id
                        UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                        Votes = thisVote,
                        WorkerID = autoid,
                        O_ServID = O_ServID,
                        OrderServices = service,Workers = worker,User = user
                    };

                    var save = context.VoteModel.Add(vm);

                       if(db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                        {
                            HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(url, "true");
                            Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                            return Json("<br />You rated " + r + " star(s), thanks !", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                        }


                    // keep the school voting flag to stop voting by this member
                    //HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(url, "true");
                    //Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    //}
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
                return Json("Rating Failed!", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(url, "true");
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

                return Json(ex.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

                throw;
            }
        }






        public ActionResult VoteNow(int id, int serv)
        {
            ViewData["id"] = id;
            ViewData["serv"] = serv;

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult VoteShow()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Model==>>

this is table schema where record has to be stored..

```
namespace WebApplication5.Models

{
    public class VoteModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int AutoId { get; set; }
        public int O_ServID { get; set; } 
        public OrderService OrderServices { get; set; }
        public int WorkerID { get; set; } 
        public Worker Workers { get; set; }
        public Int16 Votes { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

}
```

view==>>
my view code is as follows...
sending data with json to controller with different parameters pass through ViewData[] ..

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "VoteNow";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutUser.cshtml";
}
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div id="page-inner">
        <h2>VoteNow</h2>

        @model string
        @{
            var url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
        }
        @if (Request.Cookies[url] == null)
        {
            <div id="ratingDiv" class="smallText">
                Poor
                <img src="/img/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="1" /><img src="/img/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="2" /><img src="/img/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="3" /><img src="/img/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="4" /><img src="/img/whitestar.gif" alt="" class="ratingStar" data-value="5" /> Excellent
                <label id="lblResult"></label>
            </div>
            <style type="text/css">
                .ratingStar {
                    cursor: pointer;
                    height: 20px;
                    width: 20px;
                }
            </style>

        }
        else
        {
            <text><span style="color:green;"> Thanks for your vote !</span></text>
        }

        @section scripts{
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var clickedFlag = false;
                $(".ratingStar").mouseover(function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "/img/yellowstar.gif").prevAll("img.ratingStar").attr("src", "/img/yellowstar.gif");
                });
                $(".ratingStar, #radingDiv").mouseout(function () {
                    $(this).attr("src", "/img/whitestar.gif");
                });
                $("#ratingDiv").mouseout(function () {
                    if (!clickedFlag) {
                        $(".ratingStar").attr("src", "/img/whitestar.gif");
                    }
                });
                $(".ratingStar").click(function () {
                    clickedFlag = true;
                    $(".ratingStar").unbind("mouseout mouseover click").css("cursor", "default");

                    var url = "/CDashboard/SendRating?r=" + $(this).attr("data-value") + "&s=@((int)ViewData["serv"])&id=@((int)ViewData["id"])&url=@url";
                    $.post(url, null, function (data) {
                        $("#lblResult").html(data);
                    });
                });
                $("#lblResult").ajaxStart(function () {
                    $("#lblResult").html("Processing ....");
                });
                $("#lblResult").ajaxError(function () {
                    $("#lblResult").html("<br />Error occured.");
                });
            </script>
        }
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it is going to save only if rating is 5, you got a switch case there. Is it showing rating failed when rating is 5?

Comment: rating failed is always displayed whenever i rate 5 or below than 5.

Comment: Have you debugged to see if db.SaveChanges is returning 0 when rating is 5?

Comment: i added a break point on try block ..compiler stop at break point and also shows rating failed..

Comment: you should put break point at `if(db.SaveChanges() > 0)` when rating is 5 and then tell us what program does.

Comment: i added break point on if(db.save()>0),but compiler instead of going to that break point it displays rating failed

Comment: You can step through each line of code while debugging  (use F10) and see how runtime is executing your code. You will know then why it is not reaching to db.saveChanges.

Comment: Thank you so much i have accomplished my task...